# Large $wpdb query causes 502 Bad Gateway (too big header) -- Increasing Fast-CGI buffer partially fixes

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

This WordPress site uses a large front end form to create/update posts and many custom fields. Initially, the forms overwhelmed fast-cgi causing a 502 Bad Gateway. Increasing buffer size resolved the issue. [See here.](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/11312172) [And here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539501/nginx-502-bad-gateway-solved-by-increasing-buffer-why) Now, a front end form is encountering the buffer limit (despite having increased its size) causing the 502 once again. Attempting to increase buffer size further results in a 405 Not Allowed. Am concerned that already the buffer size is too large.

nginx error:

```
2022/10/26 18:09:15 [error] 70997#0: *47 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /?post_type=custom_scan&p=12450 HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/roa/Library/Application Support/Local/run/zJJZ9KiTe/php/php-fpm.socket:", host: "oneoption.local", referrer: "http://oneoption.local/?post_type=custom_scan&p=12450"
```

Current buffer settings:

```
fastcgi_pass php;
fastcgi_buffer_size      128k;
fastcgi_buffers          64 64k;
fastcgi_read_timeout     1200s;

proxy_buffer_size        128k;
proxy_buffers            64 64k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size  512k;
```

Query causing issue (note the `foreach` commented out - the form currently submits successfully with these commented out; uncommenting these [as desired] results in the 502)

```
$fields = (object) [
  'checkbox_groups' => ['trendline_20','trendline_20_breach','trendline_60','trendline_60_breach','trade_signal','trade_signal_new','divergence','strength_vs_spy','strength_vs_sector','compression_out','range_90_10','climax','adx','ha_rev_i-i','ha_rev_iiii','ha_ii','ha_cont_ii','stochastic','algo_lines','algo_lines_new'],
  'checkbox_groups_neutral' => ['compression_in','heavy_volume'],
  'bools' => ['pre_earnings_today','post_earnings_today','post_earnings_bull','post_earnings_bear','weekly_options','only_etfs','no_etfs','bullish_climax_long_term','bearish_climax_long_term','greater_prior_high','less_prior_low','greater_20d_high','less_20d_low','greater_52w_high','less_52w_low','greater_sma20','greater_sma50','greater_sma100','greater_sma200','less_sma20','less_sma50','less_sma100','less_sma200','short_squeeze'],
  'ranges' => ['option_liquidity', 'option_iv_atm','stock_price','heavy_volume_today','heavy_volume_yesterday','twenty_day_vol','stock_volatility','percent_60_day_range'],
  'ranges_date' => ['earnings_date_projected','earnings_date_previous','pre_earn_bull','pre_earn_bear'],
];

$post_id = get_the_ID();

 if ( isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) && current_user_can( 'manage_options', $post_id ) ) {

    if(!empty($_POST['title']))
    {
      $new_slug = $new_title = sanitize_title($_POST['title']);
        wp_update_post(
            array (
                'ID'        => $_POST['post_id'],
                'post_title' => $new_title,
                'post_content'  =>  $_POST['description'],
                'post_name' => $new_slug,
                'post_status'   => 'draft',
            )
        );
    }


    $items = [];

    foreach ($fields->checkbox_groups as &$value) {
      $items[$value] = serialize([$_POST[$value.'-m5bull'], $_POST[$value.'-m5bear'], $_POST[$value.'-m15bull'], $_POST[$value.'-m15bear'], $_POST[$value.'-m30bull'], $_POST[$value.'-m30bear'], $_POST[$value.'-h1bull'], $_POST[$value.'-h1bear'], $_POST[$value.'-h2bull'], $_POST[$value.'-h2bear'], $_POST[$value.'-h4bull'], $_POST[$value.'-h4bear'], $_POST[$value.'-d1bull'], $_POST[$value.'-d1bear']]);
      $items['_'.$value] = acf_get_field_key($value, $rndmID);
    }

    foreach ($fields->checkbox_groups_neutral as &$value) {
      $items[$value] = serialize([$_POST[$value.'-m5'], $_POST[$value.'-m15'], $_POST[$value.'-m30'], $_POST[$value.'-h1'], $_POST['-h2'], $_POST[$value.'-h4'], $_POST[$value.'-d1']]);
      $items['_'.$value] = acf_get_field_key($value, $rndmID);
    }

    // foreach ($fields->ranges as &$value) {
    //   $items[$value.'_bool'] = $_POST[$value.'_bool'];
    //   $items['_'.$value.'_bool'] = acf_get_field_key($value.'_bool', $rndmID);
    //   $items[$value.'_min'] = $_POST[$value.'_min'];
    //   $items['_'.$value.'_min'] = acf_get_field_key($value.'_min', $rndmID);
    //   $items[$value.'_max'] = $_POST[$value.'_max'];
    //   $items['_'.$value.'_max'] = acf_get_field_key($value.'_max', $rndmID);
    // }

    // foreach ($fields->ranges_date as &$value) {
    //   $items[$value.'_bool'] = $_POST[$value.'_bool'];
    //   $items['_'.$value.'_bool'] = acf_get_field_key($value.'_bool', $rndmID);
    //   $items[$value.'_min'] = $_POST[$value.'_min'];
    //   $items['_'.$value.'_min'] = acf_get_field_key($value.'_min', $rndmID);
    //   $items[$value.'_max'] = $_POST[$value.'_max'];
    //   $items['_'.$value.'_max'] = acf_get_field_key($value.'_max', $rndmID);
    // }

    // foreach ($fields->bools as &$value) {
    //   $items[$value] = $_POST[$value.'_bool'];
    //   $items['_'.$value] = acf_get_field_key($value, $rndmID);
    // }

    $values = [];
    foreach ( $items as $key => $value ) {
        $values[] = $wpdb->prepare( "(%d,%s,%s)", $post_id, $key, $value );
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ";
    $query .= implode( ",\n", $values );
    global $wpdb;
    // delete all meta first https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/better-way-to-update-multiple-fields-update_field/
    $wpdb->query(
      $wpdb->prepare(
        "
          DELETE FROM wp_postmeta
          WHERE post_id = %d
        ",
        $post_id
      )
    );
    //update fields
    $wpdb->query( $query );

    //redirect
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($post_id)); exit;
  }
```